# How to make a button that increment through options?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.8

[image: The button I need to make]

I am trying to make a button to scroll/increment through 4 options. Addition (+), Subtraction(-), Multiplication(*), and Divison(/).  I have no idea how to start this. I am using this button with PHP in Laravel.